# How do I combine multiple GitHub source code files into a single listing?

Tags: listings

I currently have the following command that I use to create a listing from a GitHub-hosted file:

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\GitHubFile} { O{foo-default-group} m m m } {%
|"wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/#1/#2/#3/#4"
}
```

I then create the listing as follows:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Java, firstline=8]{
    \GitHubFile{foo-repo}{master}{foo/bar/Foo.java}
}
```

This generates the following (correct) output:

[image]

My question is:

> How can I create a new command (or modify the existing command) so
> that I can combine multiple `\GitHubFile`s into a single listing?

For example, in pseudocode:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Java]{
    \GitHubFile{foo-repo}{master}{foo/bar/Foo.java}
    \GitHubFile{foo-repo}{master}{foo/bar/Bar.java}
}
```

And that would output something like the following:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.dzone.book.spring.rest")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
        Car car = context.getBean(Car.class);
        car.start();
    }
}

class Bar {
   // ...some content
}
```

Assuming that the content of `Bar.java` is:

```
class Bar {
   // ...some content
}
```

I know there are addons that I want to include later (such as being able to include only lines `a` through `b` in each file, so that `Foo.java` only have lines 8-10 and `Bar.java` only has lines 2-6, etc.), but those can be added later.

Thank you for your help.